# Creating parameterized objects generating Raw Type warnings in Java

Tags: java, generics

This is a homework problem, and I've been looking around the net for a while for some guidance.  There are several "raw type" questions on stackoverflow, but I'm not sure that I've found one that helps.

So, here goes.

I have been given an abstract class called Products.  There are a three subclasses of Products - Food, OfficeGoods and Services.

Food is subclassed into Dairy, Fruits, Grains.
OfficeGoods is subclassed into PaperGoods, Writing, Computer
Services is subclassed into DeliveryService and CleaningService.

I have to write a few Order classes - starting with a GenericOrder that will accept object of "top 3" subclasses - Food, OfficeGoods, Services.  Added objects are stored in an ArrayList for use later on.

I then need to subclass the GenericOrder into a FoodOrder and OfficeOrder.  FoodOrder needs to take accept objects of Foods and Services, and OfficeOrder needs to accept objects of OfficeGoods and Services.

So far, I am able to get the above working just fine with bounds and such.

The next step is to create an OrderProcessor class that will be of a type of GenericOrder's subclasses.  I am running into "*subclass* is a raw type.  References to a generic type *subclass* should be parameterized" warnings.

The definition for GenericOrder is:

```
public class GenericOrder<T extends Product>
```

The two order subclasses look like:

```
public class FoodOrder<T extends Product> extends GenericOrder<T>
```

The definition for OrderProcessor is:

```
public class OrderProcessor<T extends GenericOrder<?>>
```

I am specifically getting the warning in the OrderProcessor class, when I create an OrderProcessor:

```
OrderProcessor<FoodOrder> opTest1 = new OrderProcessor<FoodOrder>();
```

The program seems to work far, but I'd like to know what's going on, and how to fix it.

Sorry for the long post.  I can post more detail if required...

Comment: Thanks for attempting to explain, but please post the raw code; it's generally easier to follow, and it's unambiguous.

Comment: `FoodOrder` takes a Parameter also `public class FoodOrder<T extends Product>`. You're calling `FoodOrder` like this `OrderProcessor<FoodOrder>`. Maybe if you do this `OrderProcessor<FoodOrder<Product>>` you'll get rid of the warning. If you used the former, you'd be using the raw type of `FoodOrder`